# $ 3 \sum^{n}_{k=1} \sqrt{k} \geq 2n \sqrt{n} + 1, n \in \mathbb{N} \setminus \{0\}$ Induction proof. How to separate multiplication.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, induction

I have a problem with induction proofs like this one:

$$ 3 \sum^{n}_{k=1} \sqrt{k} \geq 2n \sqrt{n} + 1, n \in \mathbb{N} \setminus \{0\}$$

In the base case it works fine (for $n = 1$):
$$3 * \sqrt{1} \geq 2 + 1 \implies 3 = 3$$

Thesis ~ as above.

Now for $n + 1$:

$$ 3 \sum^{n+1}_{k=1} \sqrt{k} \geq 2(n+1) \sqrt{n+1} + 1$$

$$ 3 \sum^{n}_{k=1} \sqrt{k} + 3\sqrt{n+1} \geq 2n\sqrt{n+1} +1 + 2\sqrt{n+1}$$

And here is my problem: I don't know how to separate $1$ form $n$ in $2n\sqrt{n+1}$ on the left hand side.

On the right hand side of the inequality I got a sum which is good, but I can not separate that multiplication on the right. I thought about:

- using Bernoulis inequality, but then I "loose" the square root and can not use my induction thesis.
- changing $1$ under the square root for $1$ outside, but then the inequality doesn't work - right hand side is too big
- putting both sides of inequality in $e^{ln\{\}}$, but it doesn't work either

I don't know whot to do and it is not the first time I am having exactly the same problem in induction proofs. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Induction based proof:

Assume true for $n$. For $n + 1$, we have
\begin{align*}
\sqrt{n + 1} & \geq \sqrt{n} \\
\implies \sqrt{n + 1} & \geq \frac{2n}{\sqrt{n} + \sqrt{n+1}} \\
\implies \sqrt{n + 1} & \geq 2n(\sqrt{n+1} - \sqrt{n}) \\
\implies 2n \sqrt{n} + \sqrt{n + 1} & \geq 2n\sqrt{n+1}.
\end{align*}

Thus,
$ \displaystyle 2(n+1)\sqrt{n + 1} + 1 \leq 2n \sqrt{n} + 1 + 3\sqrt{n + 1} \leq 3\sum_{k = 1}^n \sqrt{k} + 3\sqrt{n + 1} \leq 3\sum_{k = 1}^{n+1} \sqrt{k}$, as required.

Answer (score 2):

For the induction step, we have:

\begin{align}
3\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\sqrt k &= 3\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sqrt k + 3\sqrt{n+1}\\
&\ge2n \sqrt n + 1 + 3\sqrt {n+1}\\
&=2(n+1)\sqrt{n+1}+1-2n(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt n)+\sqrt {n+1}\\
&=2(n+1)\sqrt{n+1}+1-\frac {2n}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt n}+\sqrt {n+1}\\
&\ge 2(n+1)\sqrt{n+1}+1-\frac {2n}{2\sqrt n}+\sqrt {n+1}\\
&= 2(n+1)\sqrt{n+1}+1-\sqrt n+\sqrt {n+1}\\
&> 2(n+1)\sqrt{n+1}+1
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

Here is a careful derivation that outlines the reasoning process in induction proofs.

First, it's important to distinguish what you **know** to be true from what you **want** to be true. If the proposition holds for $n$, you **know** that

$$3\sum_{k=1}^n\sqrt k\ge 2n\sqrt n + 1\tag1$$
To show the proposition holds for $n+1$ you **want** to show
$$3\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\sqrt k\ge 2(n+1)\sqrt {n+1} + 1\tag2$$
You are allowed to use (1) to get to (2). In anticipation of using (1), you write
$$3\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\sqrt k = 3\sum_{k=1}^n\sqrt k + 3\sqrt{n+1}
$$
and then plug in (1):
$$3\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\sqrt k \ge 2n\sqrt n + 1 + 3\sqrt{n+1}
$$
So what you *want* to be true is:
$$2n\sqrt n + 1 + 3\sqrt{n+1}\ge 2(n+1)\sqrt {n+1} + 1\tag3
$$
To verify this, the first step is to do algebra to simplify (3) into an equivalent but simpler statement. So get rid of the $2\sqrt{n+1} + 1$ that's common to both sides. This leaves the equivalent assertion, which still requires proof:
$$ 2n\sqrt n +\sqrt{n+1}\ge 2n\sqrt{n+1}\tag4$$
The other answers offer several ways to arrive at (4). Another approach is to rearrange into yet another equivalent statement (still requires proof), with $\sqrt n$ on one side and $\sqrt{n+1}$ on the other:
$$
2n\sqrt n\ge (2n-1)\sqrt{n+1}\tag5
$$
Now square both sides:
$$4n^3\ge (2n-1)^2(n+1)\tag6$$
Is (6) true? If so, then run the argument backwards from (6) to (3). If the reverse chain of implications is still valid, you are done. (Note that $n$ is at least $1$, so the step (5) $\to$ (6) is indeed reversible.)

Answer (score 1):

For many problems of this kind, once you prove the base case you only need to compare the increment from $n$ to $n+1$ on both sides,

$$3\sqrt{n+1} \ge 2((n+1)\sqrt{n+1}-n\sqrt n) \\
\iff 2n\sqrt{n} \ge (2n-1)\sqrt{n+1}\\
\iff 4n^3 \ge (2n-1)^2(n+1)=4n^3-3n+1\\
\iff 3n\ge 1$$
which is true.

One added benefit is this can be easily converted to a non-induction, telescopic proof.